# java.lang.IllegalStateException for sonarqube scanning for .Net solution

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am running Sonar-Scanner through Jenkins and unable to get the analysis successful for .Net solution. Below is the attached screenshot of the error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCAKV.png)

The error shows that 
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Line 295 is out of range in the file (...) (lines: 294)

But there are only 294 lines in this file.

I am using below versions:
sonar-scanner-msbuild-3.0.2.656
sonarqube-6.6

Comment: What coverage tool are you using? And when are you generating the coverage report files that SonarQube is reading?

Comment: Maybe a problem with the source file encoding?

Comment: We are using codecoverage.exe  which we get from the Visual Studio Enterprise

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with bamboo and dotnet-core.

It occured with a file that went down on number of lines.
The problem seemed to be that sonar was using the cache, thats why it looked for a line out of range.

The solution in my case was,in bamboo jargon, to force a clean build, or in jenkins jargon, execute on a clean workspace .